# How to calculate greatest common divisor of two numbers, A and B where both of them can be as large as 10^30?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given two number `A` and `B`. I have to calculate `gcd(A, B)`. But the problem is, both of them can be as large as `10^30`, which is too large to store in any primitive data type in C++. I know it can be easily solved by using BigInteger class in java. But, how to solve this problem in C++?

Comment: Find some library that provides a BigInteger-like class in C++?

Comment: [Gnu GMP](https://gmplib.org/) provides big integers for C and C++, similar to Java BigInteger.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I am trying to solve this problem in a online judge which doesn't accept any use of external library such as Gnu GMP or others.

Comment: if you're doing a problem to submit to an OJ why not just switch languages?

Comment: @Primusa I wanted to know if there is any other way to solve this problem without using built-in library function like BigInteger.

Comment: Using Euclid's method, it runs in *O(log n)* iterations, but each iteration will require a modulo, which is not constant time for arbitrary large numbers.

Comment: How are these numbers provided to you?  As decimal strings?

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `10^30` has length `30`, which is pretty small. In that range his only problem is implementing computing remainder (since using a library is not allowed for him).

Comment: @conditionalMethod: well two 64-bit numbers should be sufficient, so it's not that hard :)

Comment: Do you have access to a compiler with `int128_t` support?

Comment: The binary GCD algorithm is easy to implement directly on strings.  You just need subtract, divide-by-2 and multiply-by-2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: @Eljay no..it doesn't support int128_t.

Comment: Note: these sorts of challenge problems are designed to make the simple solution to the problem either impossible or too slow. Often you need to start by researching sneaky math tricks you can exploit to beat the problem down to size.

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to delete a comment...my question has aleady been answered.